# ImeOptions not working with AppCompatEditText

Tags: java, android, imeoptions

I have a fragment that contains EditText and I am trying to setup keyboard event but it doesn't seem to work. The `actionId` is always `0`.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText
    android:id="@+id/input_name"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="@string/hint_name"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:imeOptions="actionNext"
    android:digits="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"/>
```

```
name.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
        boolean handled = false;
        if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_NEXT) {
            save();
            handled = true;
        }
        return handled;
    }
});
```

I have also tried to set button label using following code but it does not work

```
name.setImeActionLabel("Next", KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER);
```

Comment: [digit](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/digit): any of the Arabic figures of 1 through 9 and 0.

Answer (score 0):

I think you misunderstood with `android:digits`

Check out [android:digits](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:digits)

> If set, specifies that this TextView has a numeric input method and
>   that these specific characters are the ones that it will accept. If
>   this is set, numeric is implied to be true. The default is false.

`android:digit` specifies that this `editText` will only accept digits. In your case you are defining it with `abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ` which have no digit, which results in **No `onEditorAction()` tirgger**.

Further, **actionId will be 0 if you set `setImeActionLabel()`.**

Ps,

 If you want to filter input of an `editText`, you should go for `InputFilter` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Specifying `android:digits` to alphabets is only accepting alphabets and any other button click in keyboard is ignored. Thus remove the attribute `digits` to `EditText` and add validation to data entered in java file.